# Unseparability of two linked rings in higher dimensions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

I am not familiar with topology. We know that in $R^3$, we cannot separate two "rings": two copies of $S^1$, if they are "linked".

I wonder that is there any similar results for two copies of $S^1\times I^k$ embedded in $R^{2k+3}, I:= [-1,1]$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some keywords: "knotted spheres," "knotted tori," "knotted surfaces."

Answer (score 3):

A pair of circles can be unlinked in any dimension above three.  Thickening the rings doesn't change this.  However, it is possible to have linked $n$-spheres inside of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.